# Declaration of objects vs their assignment in Java

Tags: java, variable-assignment, variable-declaration

```
interface Drivable{}
class Vehicle implements Drivable{}
class Car extends Vehicle{}

Vehicle x= new Vehicle();
Drivable x= new Vehicle();
Car x = new Vehicle();
Object x = new Vehicle();
Vehicle[] x = new Vehicle();
```

how many of those are right?
I am confused that if the second one Drivable=... 
and 4th Object x=.. are right

Comment: Why don't you **try them out**, i.e. do a little **research** of your own?

Comment: A quick search on inheritance will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Car x = new Vehicle(); is wrong, and Vehicle[] x = new Vehicle(); is wrong.

The 2nd statement is good - no problem with having an iterface declared which points to a concrete implementation of the interface. Best practice actually (abstraction and hiding the implementation).

The 3rd statement is illegal - you cannot declare a concrete implementation which will reference the base class. Why ? you will be missing expected behaviors of the declared type....

The 4th statement is good, similiar to the 2nd statement only with using a base implementing class instead of an interface.

The 5th statement is wrong but easy to fix : 
Vehicle[] x = {new Vehicle()};

Answer (score 0):

All of your classes are of type "Drivable"

"Vechile" is of type "Drivable", "Car" is of type "Vehicle", therefore a "Car" is a "Vehicle".

Both a "Car" and a "Vehicle" are "Drivable".

All of your initializations are correct, except the "Car x = new Vehicle();" and  the array initialization, which should look like this

```
Vehicle[] x = new Vehicle[] { 
    //Vehicles go here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong, because every car is vehicle but not the other way i.e. every vehicle may not be a car. Inheritance is "type of" i.e. car is type of vehicle.

```
Car x = new Vehicle();
```

Here the x is of array type, so the initialization is wrong.

```
Vehicle[] x = new Vehicle();
```

It should be

```
Vehicle[] x = new Vehicle[size];
```